# Unity camera starting position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

Hello so I created a camera for a RTS game I'm making but on start the camera is on the minHight position and I cant figure out how to change it hope someone helps the code is a bit of a mess its just for a test here is the code I want it to start from the maxHight position that is given and not on the minHight .

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RtsCamera : MonoBehaviour {


    public float zoomSensitivy = 15;
    private Transform m_Transform;
    public float screenEdgeBorder = 25f;
    public bool useScreenEdgeInput = true;
    public float screenEdgeMovementSpeed = 3f;

    // zoom stuff
    public float heightDampening = 5f;
    public float scrollWheelZoomingSensitivity = 25f;
    public float maxHeight = 10f; //maximal height
    public float minHeight = 15f; //minimnal height
    public LayerMask groundMask = -1;
    public bool autoHeight = true;
    public bool limitMap = true;
    public float limitX = 50f; //x limit of map
    public float limitZ = 50f; //z limit of map
    private float zoomPos = 0; //value in range (0, 1) used as t in Matf.Lerp
    public bool useScrollwheelZooming = true;

    Vector3 tempPos;


    public string zoomingAxis = "Mouse ScrollWheel";

    private float ScrollWheel
    {
        get { return Input.GetAxis(zoomingAxis); }
    }

    private Vector2 MouseAxis
    {
        get { return new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"), Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y")); }
    }
    private Vector2 MouseInput
    {
        get { return Input.mousePosition; }
    }


    private void Start()
    {

        m_Transform = transform;

    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        Move();
        LimitPosition();
        HeightCalculation();







    }
    private void Move()
    {


        if (useScreenEdgeInput)
        {
            Vector3 desiredMove = new Vector3();

            Rect leftRect = new Rect(0, 0, screenEdgeBorder, Screen.height);
            Rect rightRect = new Rect(Screen.width - screenEdgeBorder, 0, screenEdgeBorder, Screen.height);
            Rect upRect = new Rect(0, Screen.height - screenEdgeBorder, Screen.width, screenEdgeBorder);
            Rect downRect = new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, screenEdgeBorder);

            desiredMove.x = leftRect.Contains(MouseInput) ? -1 : rightRect.Contains(MouseInput) ? 1 : 0;
            desiredMove.z = upRect.Contains(MouseInput) ? 1 : downRect.Contains(MouseInput) ? -1 : 0;

            desiredMove *= screenEdgeMovementSpeed;
            desiredMove *= Time.deltaTime;
            desiredMove = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0f, transform.eulerAngles.y, 0f)) * desiredMove;
            desiredMove = m_Transform.InverseTransformDirection(desiredMove);

            m_Transform.Translate(desiredMove, Space.Self);
        }

    }
    private void LimitPosition()
    {
        if (!limitMap)
            return;

        m_Transform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.Clamp(m_Transform.position.x, -limitX, limitX),
            m_Transform.position.y,
            Mathf.Clamp(m_Transform.position.z, -limitZ, limitZ));
    }

    private void HeightCalculation()
    {
        float distanceToGround = DistanceToGround();
        if (useScrollwheelZooming)
            zoomPos += ScrollWheel * Time.deltaTime * scrollWheelZoomingSensitivity;


        zoomPos = Mathf.Clamp01(zoomPos);

        float targetHeight = Mathf.Lerp(minHeight, maxHeight, zoomPos);
        float difference = 0;

        if (distanceToGround != targetHeight)
            difference = targetHeight - distanceToGround;

       m_Transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(m_Transform.position,
            new Vector3(m_Transform.position.x, targetHeight + difference, m_Transform.position.z), Time.deltaTime * heightDampening);
    }
    private float DistanceToGround()
    {
        Ray ray = new Ray(m_Transform.position, Vector3.down);
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, groundMask.value))
            return (hit.point - m_Transform.position).magnitude;

        return 0f;
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the value of the variable `zoomPos` on line 25 to either 1 or 0 depending on whether you want it at the min height or the max height, you could do this either in the `Start()` or just at the declaration of the variable.

This is because in the `HeightCalculation` function it sets the height to somewhere between the min and max based off the value of `zoomPos`, as you use the scrollwheel this value changes and so does the zoom. Altering `zoomPos` before you run the game allows you to effectively set a default starting height.